# Python: Lists within lists - function that adds string to item in parent list without affecting child list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have generated a list of lists using:

```
board = []
for i in range(0,5):
    board.append(["#"] * 4)
```

Which returns:

```
 [['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

And have made them print on separate lines using this function:

```
def print_board(board):
for row in board:
    print row
```

Which outputs:

```
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
```

I am looking for some sort of method that will allow me to edit items in the 'board' list, adding strings to items in 'board', but not altering the child lists that are already items in 'board'.

For instance, board[0].function('A') would make 'board' return something like:

```
[['#', '#', '#', '#'] A, ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

And the print_board function would return:

```
['#', '#', '#', '#'] A
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
```

I suppose a condensed version of my problem is: Is there a function that can add strings to items in a list, which are themselves lists, or is this just impossible syntax?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as an easier way to generate your matrix:

```
>>> LoL=[['#']*4 for i in range(5)]
>>> LoL
[['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

And use .insert to add an element to a list in a given location:

```
>>> LoL.insert(1,'A')
>>> LoL
[['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A', ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

The issue is, perhaps, mixing types. You can solve this by using one more level of list:

```
>>> LoL=[[['#']*4] for i in range(5)]
>>> LoL
[[['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']]]
```

Then you can use append instead of insert:

```
>>> LoL[0].append('A')
>>> LoL
[[['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A'], [['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']], [['#', '#', '#', '#']]]
```

Then it is easier to print, since the list is homogeneous:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(str(i)[1:-1] for i in LoL)
['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A'
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
```

You can also use a dictionary for each row:

```
>>> d={i:l for i,l in enumerate(LoL)}   #assuming that is just a LoL
>>> d
{0: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 1: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 2: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 3: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 4: [['#', '#', '#', '#']]}
>>> d[0].append('A')
>>> d
{0: [['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A'], 1: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 2: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 3: [['#', '#', '#', '#']], 4: [['#', '#', '#', '#']]}
>>> d[0]
[['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A']
```

Then print that by sorting the keys of the dict:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(str(d[k])[1:-1] for k,v in sorted(d.items()) )
['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A'
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
```

---

**Edit**

You can print this way:

```
>>> for row in LoL:
...    for items in row:
...        print items,
...    print
... 
['#', '#', '#', '#'] A
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#']
```

Comment: Your method seems to work the way I want, but is there a way to remove the quotation marks from the A?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class, something like this:

```
class Row(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        list.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self._str = ''

    def add(self, value):
        self._str += value

    def __str__(self):
        return list.__str__(self) + ' ' + self._str

board = []
for i in range(0,5):
    board.append(Row(["#"] * 4))

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print row

board[0].add('A')

print_board(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to append items to a list within a list? Maybe you could try something like

`list[1].append("string")`

And replace 1 with the place of the list within the big list. Or maybe assign a new variable with a list and append that variable to a list, that way it would be easier and more straightforward.

Sorry if I didn't understand your question. I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to a list whatever you want and combine items as you wish in them, but on your example above, the string 'A' is somehow floating there not really being a part of the list, so that syntax doesn't make sense.

If all you want to do is to somehow have rows that can grow dinamically, you could put your lists inside of lists (representing a row), and so you can add items (of any kind) to the rows like this:

```
board = [
[['#', '#', '#', '#'], 'A'],
[['#', '#', '#', '#']]
[['#', '#', '#', '#']]
[['#', '#', '#', '#']]
[['#', '#', '#', '#']]]
```

To access the first row and add the 'A' you would just do: `board[0].append('A')`

I hope this answers your question.